# OAuth2 is not working for accounts other than admin accounts. What part of configuration am i missing?

Tags: oauth-2.0, imap, google-oauth, gmail-imap

I created a free domain account on www.mygbiz.com. I used this account to create client ID and secret and then followed the process of generating access tokens. The OAuth2 mechanism works perfectly fine for this admin account. However when i add users to this account and add the same users as team members on Admin console (under the team tab): https://code.google.com/apis/console/ , and then use those user accounts in my application, the OAuth2 fails for other accounts and gives the following error:

> {"status":"400","schemes":"Bearer","scope":"https://mail.google.com/"}

E.g.
admin account: admin@XYZ.mygbiz.com
This account has been used to generate client ID and Secret. The code works fine for this account. But for the other users on the same domain: 
user1: user1@XYZ.mygbiz.com
user2: user2@XYZ.mygbiz.com

The code does not work even after adding them as team members on the API console

Am i missing some part of configuration? Can someone please help here?

Comment: What process did you follow to get access tokens?

Exactly what request are you making when you get the 400 error?

Comment: Actually i followed the following process:

Comment: 1. Obtain the Client ID and secret for "Intsalled application"
2. Generate access tokens by adding the mail.google.com scope.
3. Connect to imap and then making a request by following command:
AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 encoded_oauth2_string
4. Encoded oauth2_string is obtained by adding following string:
string = user=user@XYZ.mygbiz.com^Aauth=Bearer <Access token>^A^A
5. The above algo works fine when in above string user = email address which was used to generate client ID and secret. But for other users on the same domain, the algo gives error 400.

Comment: I feel i have done some mistake while generating access token. Can you suggest the process to be followed to generate single access token for all the domain users? Do i need to create Client Id and secret through service account rather than installed application?